# Twilio Studio - how to play back gathered digits individually?

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

In Twilio Studio, I am attempting to play back digits gathered by a "Gather Input On Call" widget. I have the following text specified to be spoken aloud: "You entered {{widgets.GatherPIN.Digits}}."

When this message plays, I hear something like: "You entered one thousand three hundred twenty four," rather than, "You entered one - three - two - four."

How can I specify that each digit should be read aloud individually?

Answer (score 3):

You can use liquid syntax to accomplish this.

```
{{widgets.gather_1.Digits | split: "" | join: " "}}
```

This will split the digits into an array and then join it back together with a space in between each digit.

Comment: This is the correct method of doing this, using SSML is a bit overkill when you can just use the liquid syntax, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SSML in Studio is currently not officially supported by Twilio, so it may break at some future date, but it is the easiest way to show it.

A supported way would be to use the Studio TwiML Redirect Widget and return TwimML which uses SSML as shown below. You could below TwiML in a TwiML Bin, for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>You entered<say-as interpret-as="digits"> {{Digits}}.</say-as></Say>
</Response>
```

[image]

[image]