# Twilio Flow - Say individual digits not number

Tags: twilio

In Twilio Flow, I want to say the user's number back to them

*I see you are calling from {{trigger.call.From}}*

Instead, it says it like a number, not digits  15,555,555,555

How do I get Flow to say individual digits?

Comment: A similar question was just answered for someone else, see answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63158532/twilio-studio-how-to-play-back-gathered-digits-individually

Comment: You would set the `interpret-as="telephone"`

Answer (score 0):

Send the number out to a function as a parameter

```
function change(){
var orig = event.KEY;
var removePrefix = orig.substr(2);
var newNumber = removePrefix.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
return newNumber;
}
```

it will come back like this 777-555-9999